# How to make 2 lines start from different points - graph (Python)

Tags: python, graph

This is what i want to achieve

[image]

txt file:

TimeStamp,Irradiance,Ambient_Temperature
21/7/2014 0:00,0.66,29.16
21/7/2014 0:00,0.71,29.16

i am able to make one graph start from 15 instead of 0 and capping the limit at 40 by using this code:

```
ax1.set_ylim(15,40)
```

how can i write the code for my another line to start from 0

Thanks

EDIT

```
t = [datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') for x in t ]
temp = [float(x) for i,x in enumerate(temp) if startTime<=t[i]<=endTime]

t = [x for x in t if startTime<=x<=endTime]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='white')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax1.set_ylim(15,40)
ax1.plot(t, temp, 'c', linewidth=3.3)


short_title = ('Ambient Temperature vs. Time Graph \n From {} To {} \n ')
long_title = ('\n Max AMB_TEMP Value: {:.2f} at {} , Min AMB_TEMP Value: {:.2f} at {}, Mean AMB_TEMP Value: {:.2f} at {}\n')
fig.suptitle(short_title.format(startTime, endTime), fontsize=20, color='blue')   ax1.set_title(long_title.format(max(y),min(y),fontsize=16, color='green', ha='bottom'))
plt.ylabel(u'Ambient Temperature(\u2103)', fontsize=16, color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Time ($H:M$)', fontsize=16, color='blue')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code? As it is it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: hi carlosdc, i have posted a snippet of my code on OP

Comment: Do you simply want to draw a line with the first coordinate of (0,0)?

Comment: @toothberry: you kind of need to show us t and temp.

Comment: hi carlosdc, updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to create two different y axes (you don't have to make the second one visible), as in this example:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

You can also shift the values yourself by adding/substracting a constant to all values of one of the curves, which will shift the curve resp. up/down vertically.